# GridView show me last item as half item and some often not expand

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

I'm trying to expand gridview  inside scroll view but it show me last item as half item when set height 800dp
and not expand when set height match_parent [image]

and this my class to expand gridView

public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView {

```
boolean expanded = false;

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded()
{
    return expanded;
}
```

this amethod

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded())
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
{
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
}
```

and this all xml for gridview

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"


    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycle2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#424242" />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/previous"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btprevious"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnext"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/next"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
///////
        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/mainlin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relative1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="#424242"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        linear layout

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/lin1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/img1"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tex1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="200dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lin2"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/img2"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tex2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

 linearlayout


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lin3"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/img3"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tex3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lin4"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/img4"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tex4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>
////
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lin5"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/img5"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tex5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

here agridView Cast


            <ExpandableHeightGridView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="800dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mainlin"
                android:id="@+id/grid2"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:background="#424242"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
 end of xml


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollVi
```

I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: give padding/margin from bottom & check

Comment: user scroll view to see all items

Comment: can you post your whole xml ? or just the scrollview

Comment: i post it  @Umair

Comment: not working  @user3040153

Comment: dont use fix height,change to wrap_content

Comment: @user3040153   
when i dont use fix height  not expandded

Comment: what do u mean by not expandded?

Comment: it scroll  item but not expand  all  item  to expand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your layout and after some changes it's working fine on my side. I hope it will work for you too. Here try it:

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="#424242" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/previous"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btprevious"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnext"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/next"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainlin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/lin1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/img1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tex1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="200dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lin2"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/img2"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tex2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lin3"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/img3"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tex3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lin4"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/img4"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tex4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""/>
            </LinearLayout>
            ////
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lin5"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/img5"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tex5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ExpandableHeightGridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="800dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainlin"
        android:id="@+id/grid2"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:paddingBottom = "5dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @ Umair not working when set height to  be match_parent

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik which height you are talking about ? 
The first relativeLayout or the second one ?

Comment: @ Umair   height of ExpandableHeightGridView

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik yes it won't work with match_parent height. why because you are using it in a scrollview with a relativelayout. So when you will set it to match_parent both recylerview and gridview will mess up the view. You have to give manual height in order to make it work.

Comment: @ Umair Ok but why  miss  view when match_parent?

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik as far as I understand this is because this is how relativelayout works. it will draw the layout according to the standard screen size. And once the size is finished it will just give the remaining to to your gridview like when you do match_parent. if you want to use match_parent use linearlayout and then give a weight to each portion. But I will suggest you to go out with this approach. it's fine with this.

Comment: ok thank you  i will use this approach where Linearlayout not working  for match_parent

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik Glad to help you. Happy coding :)